# Oracle insert large string into CLOB columns avoiding error ORA-01704: string literal too long

Tags: sql, oracle, clob

I have the following error with an INSERT statement with a very large string:

```
INSERT INTO MYTABLE (CLOB_COLUMN) VALUES ('string longer than 4000 characters');
```

This returns the following error:

```
ORA-01704: string literal too long
```

I've tried even the function TO_CLOB:

```
INSERT INTO MYTABLE (CLOB_COLUMN) VALUES (TO_CLOB('string longer than 4000 characters'));
```

The error is the same.

How to insert a large string in a CLOB column without concatenating the string into chunks, avoiding the error ORA-01704?

Comment: `to_clob('string less') || to_clob(' than 4000 characters')`. Or use external program and pass clob as clob. This is described [in docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-F521FBA0-FFED-4079-ABC4-9052218B3FD5): *A text literal can have a maximum length of 4000 bytes if the initialization parameter `MAX_STRING_SIZE = STANDARD`, and 32767 bytes if `MAX_STRING_SIZE = EXTENDED`*

Comment: "without concatenating" - you can't avoid the limit on literal length, no. As you're presumably copying and pasting that long string from somewhere, can you make the source available as a text file and use SQL\*Loader or an external table instead of using a manual insert? Or you can use an external tool to split the string into chunks for you, but that's still a pain.

Comment: Other databases don't have this limitation. I don't want to split the string. I want to insert the string as long as it is.

Comment: You can use PL/SQL and `DECLARE v_str VARCHAR2(32000) := 'your 32k string'; BEGIN INSERT INTO MYTABLE (CLOB_COLUMN) VALUES (TO_CLOB(v_str)); END;` but that just moves the limit from 4k to 32k.

Comment: "I don't want to split the string. I want to insert the string as long as it is." Then don't use literals. Pass the value as a CLOB bind parameter from the program you are using to access the database into a parameterised query `INSERT INTO MYTABLE (CLOB_COLUMN) VALUES (:your_bind_variable)` or load the value from a file.

Comment: @MT0 there's no more comfortable way instead to bind the variable?

Comment: That's the way oracle works.

Comment: This limitation appears only in manual inserts that is not very common way to use DBMS. If you build SQL statements properly (without SQL injection) there's no (uncomfortable) limit on host string length.